# Adding characters in front and end of specific subtitle lines in Notepad++?

Tags: regex

I want to add a dash in front of a continuing subtitle line. Like this:

Example sub (.srt):

```
1
00:00:48,966 --> 00:00:53,720
Today he was so angry and happy
at the same time,

2
00:00:53,929 --> 00:00:57,683
he went to the store and bought a
couple of books. Then the walked home

3
00:00:57,849 --> 00:01:01,102
with joy and jumped in the pool.

4
00:00:57,849 --> 00:01:01,102
One day he was in a bad mood and he
didn't get happier when he read.
```

TO THIS:

```
1
00:00:48,966 --> 00:00:53,720
Today he was so angry and happy
at the same time-

2
00:00:53,929 --> 00:00:57,683
-he went to the store and bought a
couple of books. Then the walked home-

3
00:00:57,849 --> 00:01:01,102
-with joy and jumped in the pool.

4
00:00:57,849 --> 00:01:01,102
One day he was in a bad mood and he
didn't get happier when he read.
```

The original subtitle is in Swedish. This is the standard for scandinavian subtitles.

How do I format it with regex in Notepad++? How should I write the tags and what if the subtitle contains italic tags in front and end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with the `g` and `m` modifiers:

```
(?:,|([^.?!]<[^>]+>|[^>.?!]))$(\n\n.*\n.*\n)
```

Use `$1-$2-` as the substitution.

I'm using a simple definition of sentence. If there is  one of `.?!`, that's counted as the end of a sentence. While this may not be a perfect definition, you're only looking at the ends of sentences.

Depending on several factors (for example, a line ending in ), you may need to tweak it a little.

---

Essentially, the regex is two parts.

The first part matches one of three things at the end of a line. If it matches a comma, that comma is removed. Otherwise, it looks to see if the last letter (if there is a tag, the letter before that) is NOT any of `.?!`.

The second part matches all the lines before the one that needs the dash. This also helps ensure that the end of the line you just matched is followed by a new line (and not more text).